# Gitlab object storage with S3 encrypted buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, amazon-kms

I'm trying to encrypt the S3 bucket configured for Gitlab (Helm) object storage with a CMK KMS key.
The key policy allows the user to do everything on the key (`kms:*`) and the user itself has similar permissions, but when Gitlab tries to upload the artifacts, the coordinator throws an error:

`WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "<something>" to coordinator... 500 Internal Server Error`

Gitlab's [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html#encrypted-s3-buckets) state that SSE-KMS is supported by default. What could the issue be.

Gitlab version: 15.8.0

Helm version: 6.8.0